# How to use groupby and cumcount on unique names in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
 ID ..... config_name    config_version  ...  
 aa           A                0         
 ab           A                7
 ad           A                7
 ad           A                27   
 bb           B                0     
 cc           C                0      
 cd           C                8
```

I want to groupby config_name and apply cumcount on each unique config_version so that I get an additional column like

```
 ID ..... config_name    config_version     config_version_count 
 aa           A                0                     0        
 ab           A                7                     1
 ad           A                7                     1  
 ad           A                27                    2 
 bb           B                0                     0
 cc           C                0                     0
 cd           C                8                     1
```

But I can't seem to understand how to do it.

I tried using

```
      unique_count = df.groupby('config_name')['config_version'].cumcount()
      unique_count = pd.DataFrame({'config_name': [unique_count.index], 'config_version_count: [unique.count.values]})
      df = pd.merge(df,unique_count, on = 'config_name' , how = 'left')
```

Which gives the following output

```
 ID ..... config_name    config_version     config_version_count 
 aa           A                0                     0        
 ab           A                7                     1
 ad           A                7                     2  
 ad           A                27                    3 
 bb           B                0                     0
 cc           C                0                     0
 cd           C                8                     1
```

I also tried

```
 unique_count = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('config_name')['config_version'].cumcount()
  unique_count.reindex(df.index).ffill()
  df['config_version_count'] = unique_count
```

But this gives the same output as the first try.

Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html) with [`CategoricalIndex.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.codes.html):

```
df['config_version_count'] = (df.groupby('config_name')['config_version']
                                .transform(lambda x: pd.CategoricalIndex(x).codes))

print (df)
   ID config_name  config_version  config_version_count
0  aa           A               0                     0
1  ab           A               7                     1
2  ad           A               7                     1
3  ad           A              27                     2
4  bb           B               0                     0
5  cc           C               0                     0
6  cd           C               8                     1
```

Your solution should be working:

```
df['config_version_count'] = (df.drop_duplicates(['config_name','config_version'])
                                .groupby('config_name')
                                .cumcount())
df['config_version_count'] = df['config_version_count'].ffill().astype(int)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can modify this solution to take into account NaN values, such that the cumcount function does not add anything if the config_version value is NaN?

Comment: @Pleastry - use `m = df['config_name'].notna()` and then `df.loc[m, 'config_version_count'] = (df[m].groupby('config_name')['config_version']
                                .transform(lambda x: pd.CategoricalIndex(x).codes))`

Comment: Oh, this only works if the "config_version" is sorted in ascending order. The solution is broken if config_version is [27, 0, ,NaN, 7, 7] for config_name = "A". I will try to find a solution and I will post my answer later.

Comment: Actually the second part of your solution, which is the modification to OP's solution, seems to work in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`pd.factorize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)

```
df['config_version_count']=df.groupby('config_name')['config_version'].\
                                  transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
print(df)

   ID config_name  config_version  config_version_count
0  aa           A               0                     0
1  ab           A               7                     1
2  ad           A               7                     1
3  ad           A              27                     2
4  bb           B               0                     0
5  cc           C               0                     0
6  cd           C               8                     1
```