# Pandas Replace columns with counter value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am trying to reformat my data-frame to by adding a column which represents the `counter` based on a value in a `column`. (please see below):

The Data Frame looks like:

```py
[*]: df

     sid    rid  ratio  
0  49493  19070  1.498  
1  49498  19074  1.618  
2  50599  19074  1.618  
3  51602  19019  1.394  
4  51602  19019  1.209  
5  51602  19099  1.294  
6  51602  19099  1.194
```

I would like to, `groupby` **sid** and replace the entries in `rid` with `unique occurrence-count or counter` as shown below:

```py
     sid    rid  ratio  COUNT
0  49493  19070  1.498      1
1  49498  19074  1.618      1
2  50599  19074  1.618      1
3  51602  19019  1.394      1  <-- first unique value for sid == 51602
4  51602  19019  1.209      1
5  51602  19099  1.294      2  <-- second unique value for sid == 51602
6  51602  19099  1.194      2
```

So, far i have done,

```py
df['counter'] = df.groupby('sid')['rid'].apply(ToCounter)

def ToCounter(grp):
  counts = grp.value_counts()
  uval   = grp.unique()
  ret = grp.copy(deep=True)
  for i,u in enumerate(uval):
    ret.loc[ret == u] = i + 1
  return ret
```

The Data Frame, I am working with is big and the `groupby` method is `very-slow`.

**Is there a `inbuilt function` or `simple method` which can do the trick ??**

**cumcount()**

`cumcount()` will count and return `incremental counter for occurrences`

with `cumcount()` i get, **which is not what i want**

```py
[*] df['CUMCOUNT'] = df.groupby('sid').cumcount() + 1

     sid    rid  ratio  COUNT  CUMCOUNT
0  49493  19070  1.498      1         1
1  49498  19074  1.618      1         1
2  50599  19074  1.618      1         1
3  51602  19019  1.394      1         1
4  51602  19019  1.209      1         2
5  51602  19099  1.294      2         3
6  51602  19099  1.194      2         4
```

**SOLUTION**

[how-to-use-groupby-and-cumcount-on-unique-names-in-a-pandas-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862986/how-to-use-groupby-and-cumcount-on-unique-names-in-a-pandas-column)

Comment: @jezrael please, read the edit and remove the mark

Comment: @giser_yugang This solve's my problem thank you